# Applying StyleClass to Input text

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml

I have been trying to apply style class to my input text but I am unable to do it .

```
<h:form id="SearchPageForm">
    <br />

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p:outputLabel>Search: </p:outputLabel>
    <p:inputText id="search"  styleClass="text-input" size="123"
        value="${SearchController.employeeBO.employeeID}" />

    &nbsp;<h:commandButton value="submit" image="images/search.png"
        style="vertical-align: top;" action="#{SearchController.searchOnId}" />
    <br />
    <br />
```

This is my HTML and my CSS says

```
.text-input{
background-color:#fbfbfb;
border:solid 50px #000000;
margin-bottom:8px;
width:750px;
padding:8px 5px;
color:#797979;
```

}

I did the inspect on the form and I see it is still calling the default CSS of primefaces.

```
<input id="SearchPageForm:search" name="SearchPageForm:search" type="text" size="123" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all text-input" role="textbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-multiline="false">
```

I want to increase the size of Search Form to 750px .

[image]

I am new to CSS and HTML so might have missed something .

Regards

Comment: Was able to fix it using !important in CSS . Thanks

Comment: You should avoid using !important. Inspect and see which class is overwriting the styles.

Answer (score -1):

To debug the css properties you could use the function "inspect element" that all browsers have, and so you can see if the css properties are being aplied.